# Batch file on execution is not taking the complete arguments

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have created a batch file and passing arguments to it in following way:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", report, Formattype, Output, file, NcoverArg, CoverageFile);
```

but when I am executing the batch file using echo on ( In order to check whether it is taking correct arguments ) then found that it is not taking complete argument list

My batch file content is :

```
echo on
set basedir=C:\Runner
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Gallio\bin\
Gallio.Echo.exe  %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6
```

Now from argument `%4` onward the data is not seen at command-line and hence command doesn't execute. Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: Passing path names with spaces breaks the arguments count

Answer (score 1):

Batch requires you to quote arguments with spaces within, so try:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"{3}\" \"{4}\" \"{5}\"", report, Formattype, Output, file, NcoverArg, CoverageFile);
```

You can also check all arguments in batch using

```
ECHO %*
```

Comment: Thanks steve It was a small error that i passed space after = operator and removing that helped. :)